# Using a global number in python functions

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, variables

So, i'm trying to make simple python programme that plays mp3 files wich are named as number.mp3 (1.mp3, 2.mp3...), I've two functions:

```
import pygame
import random

def random2():
    number= random.randrange (10)

def function():
    random2()
    pygame.mixer.init(44100)
    pygame.mixer.music.load(str(number) + ".mp3")
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() == True:
        continue

function()
```

random2 looks for a ranmdom number and save it as a variable called number, so then, in function y try to look for it, but the terminal (I'm running this in linux) said:

```
  File "./program.py", line 23, in <module>
    function()
  File "./program.py", line 18, in function
    pygame.mixer.music.load(str(number) + ".mp3")
NameError: global name 'number' is not defined
```

I've tried defining number at the first, as `global number` and inside the random function, but it doesn't work
Could someone help me? It may be a stupid problem but i'm starting with this, thanks

Comment: this is a very basic question about python scope. ask yourself: When does your number start to exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `random2()` function should return the random number instead of storing it in a variable. Then you can call it as `number = random2()`

Comment: If i change random2( ) to:
def random2():
    random.randrange (10)
And then in function i write number=random2() it still doesn't work
If worked with juhist's answer

Comment: Use the `return` statement to return the value from a function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def random2():
    global number
    number = random.randrange(10)

def function():
    global number
    random2()
    pygame.mixer.init(44100)
    pygame.mixer.music.load(str(number) + ".mp3")
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() == True:
        continue
```

Although if you use global variables, something is wrong. I heavily recommend the approach given in the other answer, i.e. return the value `number` from `random2()` and then call it like this: `number = random2()`

Answer (score -1):

Just declare as `number = random2 ()` ... for this make a return statement from the `random2 ()`...

Comment: `number = random2()` will only work if `random2()` returns the number. However, it doesn't ;-)

Comment: @septi oops I haven't written return part. .I edited my ans!!